# Monte Carlo integration estimating identity operator

Tags: simulation, monte-carlo

I have to calculate the estimator of

$\theta=\int_{-1}^{1}|x|e^{-x^{2}}I_{\mathbb{R}}(x)dx$

I implemented the following R code, but I am hesitating about the use of the identity operator. Would be that correct? I get a better estimation without  `identity(Sample)`.

```
n <- 16
b <- 1
a <- -1
LI <- b-a
ThetaMC <- 0
x <- runif(n)
X <-  numeric(n)
G <- 0
for (I in 1:n) {
  Sample<- 2*x[I]-1
  g <-  LI*abs(Sample)*exp(-Sample^2)*identity(Sample)
  G <- c(G,g)
  X[I] <- Sample
  ThetaMC <- ThetaMC + g/n }
ThetaMC
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: The appearance of "$I_{\mathbb R}(x)$" in the integral is superfluous: you may ignore it.  Besides, `identity` in `R` does not implement this function (not even anything like it): please consult the help page for `identity`.

Comment: Ok, thought the same. But I was hesitating why the professor wrote this in the notes. Thank you @whuber ♦ , I'll remove it.

Comment: Your professor might have had in mind something like $\int_{\mathbb R}|x|e^{-x^2}\mathcal{I}_{[-1,1]}\,\mathrm{d}x.$  BTW, here is a more idiomatic (and efficient) rendering of your algorithm whose form might shed light on the underlying concepts: `f <- function(x) abs(x) * exp(-x^2);
g <- function(a, b, n=16)  mean(f(runif(n, a, b))) * abs(b-a);
(theta <- g(-1,1))`

Comment: Awesome! thank you @whuber♦